# ERROR Tomcat: Apache - Java - Tomcat - Catalina

Tags: apache2, java, tomcat

I am trying to run a software (HTML based) and when Tomcat runs to open it, I get the following messages:

```
The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
```

And this:

```
Apr 17, 2015 2:13:58 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
```

I have tried a lot of things, no solution so far.

---

The error seems to appear several times. This is part of the LOG:

> INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /opt/OpenForisCalc/calc-server/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/calc.xml
>
> Apr 17, 2015 2:13:58 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal 
>   SEVERE: Error listenerStart
>
> Apr 17, 2015 2:13:58 AM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator createSecureRandom 
>   INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [208] milliseconds.
>
> Apr 17, 2015 2:13:58 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal 
>   SEVERE: Context [/calc] startup failed due to previous errors 
>   Apr 17, 2015 2:13:58 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
>
> SEVERE: The web application [/calc] registered the JDBC driver [org.postgresql.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.

Answer (score 0):

you faced with 1 warning and 1 error:
1) The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library - is a library, it's optional and all should working without it but with less perfomance on production system. This is a warning
2) Apr 17, 2015 2:13:58 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal SEVERE: Error listenerStart - this is a root cause of your issue. You should provide more logs for it, but I believe that the root cause of it relates to the web.xml of your application

Comment: I added more information below.